# Try/Except API Request in Tkinter still freezes sometimes?

Tags: python, tkinter

The below is from a warehouse tool made to display KPI info. The program can run for a week fine, however freeze randomly, and I think it's because of an exception that is not being caught with the Try/Except.

I figured if I wrapped the entire lot in a Try/Except than it would catch all errors and just refresh after 20 seconds as expected. It does work for the majority of the time running.

Am I missing an important exception here?

```
def importData():
    now = datetime.now()
    date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    date_yesterday = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    express_time = date.today() - timedelta(days=4)

    # --- Printed Data ---

    try:
      conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection()
      payload = ''
      headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'StarShipIT-Api-Key': '',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': ''
      }
      conn.request("GET", "/api/orders?status=Printed&sort_column=ShippedDate&sort_direction=descending&include=packages&include=events&page_size=10", payload, headers )
      res = conn.getresponse()
    

      raw_data = res.read()
      decoded_data = raw_data.decode("utf-8")
      filtered_data = re.findall(r'(?<=order_id).*?(?=Generation)',decoded_data)
      order_number = re.findall(r'(?<=order_number":").*?(?=","reference)',decoded_data)

    

     # --- Shipped Data ---

      conn2 = http.client.HTTPSConnection()
      payload2 = ''
      headers2 = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'StarShipIT-Api-Key': '',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': ''
      }
      conn2.request("GET", "/api/orders?status=Shipped&sort_column=ShippedDate&sort_direction=descending&include=packages&include=events&page_size=10", payload2, headers2 )
      res2 = conn2.getresponse()

      raw_data2 = res2.read()
      decoded_data2 = raw_data2.decode("utf-8")
      filtered_data2 = re.findall(r'(?<=order_id).*?(?=Generation)',decoded_data2)
      order_number2 = re.findall(r'(?<=order_number":").*?(?=","reference)',decoded_data2)

      stored_data.extend(x for x in filtered_data if x not in stored_data)
      stored_data.extend(x for x in filtered_data2 if x not in stored_data)
    
      order_number.extend(x for x in order_number2 if x not in order_number)

      pickle.dump(stored_data, open("stored_data.dat", "wb"))

      today_data_d = [ x for x in stored_data if "printed_date\":\"%s" % date_time in x ]
      today_data_c = [ x for x in today_data_d if "writeback_status\":\"Up to date" in x ]
      today_data_b = [ x for x in today_data_c if "writeback_details\":\"Success" in x ]
      today_data_a = [ x for x in today_data_b if "order_status\":\"Printed" in x ]
      today_data = [ x for x in today_data_a if "writeback_details\":\"Already fulfilled" not in x ]
    

      filter3_d = [ x for x in stored_data if "printed_date\":\"%s" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter3_c = [ x for x in filter3_d if "writeback_status\":\"Up to date" in x ]
      filter3_b = [ x for x in filter3_c if "writeback_details\":\"Success" in x ]
      filter3_a = [ x for x in filter3_b if "order_status\":\"Printed" in x ]
      filter3 = [ x for x in filter3_a if "writeback_details\":\"Already fulfilled" not in x ]

      filter4 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT12" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter5 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT13" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter6 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT14" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter7 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT15" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter8 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT16" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter9 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT17" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter10 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT18" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter11 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT19" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter12 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT20" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter13 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT21" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter14 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT22" % date_yesterday in x ]
      filter15 = [ x for x in filter3 if "printed_date\":\"%sT23" % date_yesterday in x ]

      filter4.extend(filter5)
      filter4.extend(filter6)
      filter4.extend(filter7)
      filter4.extend(filter8)
      filter4.extend(filter9)
      filter4.extend(filter10)
      filter4.extend(filter11)
      filter4.extend(filter12)
      filter4.extend(filter13)
      filter4.extend(filter14)
      filter4.extend(filter15)

      today_data.extend(filter4)

      print(len(today_data))
    except: window.after(20000, importData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is not recommended to use a "naked" except.
Instead, capture the info for the exception and log it, preferebly to a log file:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='example.log',
    format='%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    encoding='utf-8',
    level=logging.DEBUG
)

def importData():
    try:
        # your code goes here
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        window.after(20000, importData)
```

The reason for logging to a file is that with a `tkinter` program, you might not even see the messages on standard output.

*If* an exception occurs, you can at least see what happens in the log file.

And it would be a good idea to sprinkle some `logging.debug` calls throughout `importData`, so you can see what happens and inspect the time-stamps so you can see how long things take.
Once the code works as expected, you can configure the logging level as INFO, and the `debug` calls will be ignored.

If you are calling `importData` code with `after`, its execution will interrupt the `mainloop`.
And since network response times can be unpredictable and can take a while before they time-out, that could be the cause of the application freeze as well.

What I would suggest is to run `importData` as a second thread.
Have it start a `while`-loop get the data (in a try/except) block and then sleep for a certain time before trying again.

If you are using Python 3 and if your `tkinter` is built with threading enabled, you should be able to update widgets from the second thread, since only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. At the same time, network I/O releases the GIL so the second thread won't block the UI thread.

If you want to stop the second thread, simply set `running` to `False` from a callback in the main UI thread.

```
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk

running  = True

def import_thread():
    while running:
        try:
            # fetch data
            # process data
            # update widgets
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            # Maybe also write the error to a textbox?
        time.sleep(20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    # create window and widgets here
    it = threading.Thread(target=import_thread)
    # You could also start the thread from a menu or button callback.
    it.start()
    root.mainloop()
```